# How can I know if the specified model of Intel processor is 3rd g or 4th g?

Tags: cpu, serial-number

I need a quick and easy way to identify if the Intel processor in the specifications of a laptop is from the 3rd Generation or 4th generation without using software or internet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the model number.

3XXX is 3rd generation
4XXX is 4th generation

The 4th generation ( Q4'13 ) revision update will be 4XX1 models.  This fixes a known bug in the first revision step.

Here is the 3rd and 4th Generation i7 Product List.

[3rd Generation i7](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/65506)

[4th Generation i7](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/75023)